# Can state trie be hacked?

Tags: state-trie

Ethereum's purpose is to decentralize components in the network. There is only   one state trie in the network, Can't it be hacked and changed (because there is only one trie) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between a centralised data model and a centralised infrastructure. State trie is a centralised model, but it is maintained on a decentralised infrastructure (Ethereum Network). Hence, you'll have to hack the network in order to hack the state trie.

Comment: I see, so in order to commit changes in the trie, I will have to get an agreement in the network?

Comment: @adi Yes. A consensus bug, such as https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Value_overflow_incident, could be used to hack the state of a blockchain.